# Can't get repeat correct at the end of applescript workflow

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to get Illustrator to save all open documents according to the original file name at the end of this script. It will save whichever file comes first but I can't figure out how to loop it back to re-name the remaining file(s).The files are named numerically so sometimes the back will save an other times the front.

```
 -- get JobName
set JobName to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter Job Name:" default answer "Job_Name")

-- setup folder paths
set loc to path to desktop as text
set downloadsFolder to path to downloads folder as text
set newfo to loc & JobName & ":"
set newfoSeps to newfo & JobName & "_Seps" & ":"

-- make sure all of the folders exist
tell application "Finder"
if not (exists folder newfo) then
    make new folder at loc with properties {name:JobName}
end if

if not (exists folder newfoSeps) then
    make new folder at folder newfo with properties {name:JobName & "_Seps"}
end if

end tell

set the clipboard to JobName -- this is not a Finder command so we do not put it in the Finder block of code

-- move files to newfo and get a list of them
tell application "Finder"
open folder newfo
move (files of folder downloadsFolder) to folder newfo
set newfoFiles to (files of folder newfo) as alias list
set bounds of front window to {1648, 268, 2418, 706}
end tell

-- open each file in Illustrator and make spot colors
repeat with aFile in newfoFiles
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    activate
    open aFile
    set WindowList to name of documents --List of every open documents name repeat with CurrentWindow in WindowList 
    set theName to name of current document
    set theNamecount to count of theName
    set theOutdatedPathObj to the file path of current document
    set thePath to (POSIX path of theOutdatedPathObj) as string
    set pathCount to count of thePath
    set pathCount to (pathCount - theNamecount)
    set newPath to (text 1 thru pathCount of thePath)

    tell document 1

        set docColorSpace to color space
        if (docColorSpace is CMYK) then
            set SpotColor1 to {cyan:21.0, magenta:0, yellow:100.0, black:0.0}
            set SpotColor2 to {cyan:11.0, magenta:100, yellow:30.0, black:0.0}
            set SpotColor3 to {cyan:0.0, magenta:0, yellow:0.0, black:100.0}

        else
            set SpotColor1 to {red:206.0, green:219.0, blue:41.0}
            set SpotColor2 to {red:215.0, green:23.0, blue:111.0}
            set SpotColor3 to {red:35.0, green:34.0, blue:33.0}
        end if

        make new spot with properties {name:"Highlight White", color type:spot color, color:SpotColor1}
        make new spot with properties {name:"Under Base", color type:spot color, color:SpotColor2}
        make new spot with properties {name:"Spot Black", color type:spot color, color:SpotColor3}
    end tell
    try
        if theName contains "back" then set newName to JobName & "_FB"

        if theName contains "front" then set newName to JobName & "_FF"

        set finalPath to newPath & newName
        (save current document in file finalPath as Illustrator) -- make sure finalPath looks like this (... folder:folder:Filename.ai) Name extension is important

    end try

end tell

end repeat

end
```

Many Thanks to you for your help Tim Joe!!!

Comment: This script works and works every time and completes every task but every 3rd time will say "Can't get end". Am i missing something important to close the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like the following (may need to tweak a bit):

```
    repeat CurrentDoc in OpenDocList
    tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    active -- the current doc

    save current document in file finalPath as Illustrator -- make sure to have full file path including file extension.

    close -- if wanted
    end tell
    end repeat
```

Was a quick glance and don't see the extension in final path variable. Also Kind of weird to see activate after the save.

**Update 4/23**

Here is your loop, didn't have time to debug

```
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    activate
    set WindowList to name of documents --List of every open documents name
    repeat with CurrentWindow in WindowList
        open aFile
set theName to name of current document
    set theNamecount to count of theName
    set theOutdatedPathObj to the file path of current document
    set thePath to (POSIX path of theOutdatedPathObj) as string
    set pathCount to count of thePath
    set pathCount to (pathCount - theNamecount)
    set newPath to (text 1 thru pathCount of thePath)
    tell document 1
        set docColorSpace to color space
        if (docColorSpace is CMYK) then
            set SpotColor1 to {cyan:21.0, magenta:0, yellow:100.0, black:0.0}
            set SpotColor2 to {cyan:11.0, magenta:100, yellow:30.0, black:0.0}
            set SpotColor3 to {cyan:0.0, magenta:0, yellow:0.0, black:100.0}
        else
            set SpotColor1 to {red:206.0, green:219.0, blue:41.0}
            set SpotColor2 to {red:215.0, green:23.0, blue:111.0}
            set SpotColor3 to {red:35.0, green:34.0, blue:33.0}
        end if

        make new spot with properties {name:"Highlight White", color type:spot color, color:SpotColor1}
        make new spot with properties {name:"Under Base", color type:spot color, color:SpotColor2}
        make new spot with properties {name:"Spot Black", color type:spot color, color:SpotColor3}
    end tell

 try
        if theName contains "back" then
            set newName to JobName & "_FB"
        else
            if theName contains "front" then
                set newName to JobName & "_FF"

                set finalPath to newPath & newName
                (save current document in file finalPath as Illustrator) -- make sure finalPath looks like this (... folder:folder:Filename.ai) Name extension is important

            end if
        end if
    end try
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: I'm working with what you've suggested now - it's looking for a definition of the variable OpenDocList. I ditched the activate after the save.The last part was from a variation of Adobe's save as a pdf but was a fix for a newer version of Illustrator hence theOutdatedPathObj (it was the only one I could get to actually save). The extension is Illustrator (as opposed to eps,pdf,etc.) and the file path is defined in the block with set listed 7 times.It's not pretty, I know. I'll update my file - it will save 1 of the open docs - I think my problem may be in the if/else part and/or the loop.

Comment: That's it! Thank you for the help! I needed to rearrange the open aFile
    set & WindowList to name of documents and get rid of the else between the if statements. I think the file-path is established as an alias at the start of the Illustrator section so I didn't need to spell out the (... folder:folder:Filename.ai). I will mark this as answered shortly.